# Error during running app because of jakarta annotation

Tags: spring-boot, gradle, dependencies, grpc, jakarta-migration

I am getting this error when I try to run my Spring Boot app.

> Exception starting filter [requestContextFilter]
>
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: jakarta/annotation/PostConstruct

This is my gradle file.

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '3.1.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.3'
    id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.8.17"
}

group = 'Hospital'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
protobuf {
    protoc {
        artifact = "com.google.protobuf:protoc:3.17.3"
    }
    plugins {
        grpc {
            artifact = 'io.grpc:protoc-gen-grpc-java:1.42.1'
        }
    }
    generateProtoTasks {
        all()*.plugins {
            grpc {}
        }
    }
}
java {
    sourceCompatibility = '17'
}

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'net.devh:grpc-server-spring-boot-starter:2.15.0.RELEASE'
    implementation 'jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:1.3.5'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

I am new to gRPC and java dependencies. What is the issue here? I added javax annotations to my dependencies but I still get previous error during runtime.

Comment: Try adding `javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api` also as a dependency (as described in https://blog.coffeebeans.at/archives/1860)

Answer (score 0):

You're targeting the `1.3.5` version of `jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api` artifact.

Like other artifact's after jakarta migration, eclipse team published older `javax` artifact's with the new coordinates.

This [`1.3.5`](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.ca/releases/1.3.5) version is `javax` based

You should use version starting from [`2.0.0`](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.ca/releases/2.0.0), [`2.1.1`](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/ee4j.ca/releases/2.1.1) should be a good start.

```
    implementation 'jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:2.1.1'
```